# JPA not returning the UUID "Text" value of a MySQL varbinary field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I have a field in MySQL as varbinary(36), which stores UUID. Then i click on the field in MySQL workbench, I can see the text value of field as "4479633f-a7e5-4ea9-945c-589263022634". I use JPA in my code, when I do a SELECT U FROM USER in JPA, it turns the value as "66653565373765302D663832312D313165332D613361632D303830303230306339613636", which is the hexadecimal equivalent of the value. What should I do to let JPA return the Text value of the field.

Here is my definition of the filed in my code:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
private String countryId;
```

Answer (score 2):

A [UUID type is better stored as BINARY(16)](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/), and according to [Hibernate Types](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-hibernate-types/) you can use both a binary or a char representation.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID uuid;
```

For the String representation you would need a CHAR(32) column

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)")
private String uuidHex;
```

Comment: I am using @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)") and @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(64)"), did not work. 
I am still getting the hexadecimal equivalent of the value.

Comment: You must set the CHAR(32) column definition in MySQL. This annotation is for hbmddl and if you don't use Hibernate to generate your schema then you have to make the db change manually. Set it in your db and it should work.

Comment: @Column is defined by JPA, not hibernate proprietary.

Comment: Right, but my answer doesn't imply the contrary. Hibernate Types are the ones doing the actual mapping behind the scenes

Comment: Can I use 
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(200)")
private UUID uuid; 
To store UUID as string instead of binary in mysql ?

Comment: You are better off using a CHAR with a fixed length since UUIDs don't vary in size.